# Unable to render aspx files when uploaded to SharePoint programmatically

Tags: python, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, office365-rest-client

I am new to SharePoint. I have written a simple python script that basically connects to SharePoint and uploads files (aspx and other frontend files) from a folder on my local machine to a specific folder on SharePoint site.

To facilitate the script to communicate with the SharePoint, I have a created an App principal under SharePoint using the SharePoint App-Only model. I have done this by calling the appregnew.aspx, example: [https://spo.test.com/sites/MYSITE/\_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx](https://spo.test.com/sites/MYSITE/%5C_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx) , below is the sample page when 'appregnew.aspx' is called

[image]

Then, I have provided the below permissions to the App principal through 'appinv.aspx', example - [https://spo.test.com/sites/MYSITE/\_layouts/15/appinv.aspx](https://spo.test.com/sites/MYSITE/%5C_layouts/15/appinv.aspx)

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Next, I use the Client ID and Client Secret under the Python script to establish communication with SharePoint and to upload files to a specific folder (folder already exists and is not created by the program) on SharePoint, example path to which files are uploaded: https://spo.test.com/sites/MYSITE/Shared%20Documents/TeamDocs2

> Note: This script uses Python library 'Office365-REST-Python-Client' to communicate with SharePoint

The script can successfully authenticate itself and also upload the files to the folder on SharePoint. But then when I manually go to the SharePoint folder and click on the aspx file, example : index.aspx; the file gets downloaded instead of getting rendered.

There is no issue with the file i.e. it is not corrupted because when I manually upload the same file onto the same folder, then there is no issue, the file gets rendered.

In regards to the permissions for the App principal, I've already given 'FullControl' at the scope 'sitecolletion/web' level. I also tried changing the scope from 'http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web' to 'http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection', this didn't work as well

Please can somebody help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. After spending significant amount of time trying to fix this issue, I just simply created a new SharePoint site and then enabled Custom Script in SharePoint using the PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the .aspx page is being downloaded is related to security risk mitigation in SharePoint.  If you consider that Javascript (.js) files and .aspx files are **executable** files in the browser, then it should also be self evident that allowing users to upload such files to SharePoint could pose risk.  Because of this, Microsoft has disabled custom script on all modern sites by default.  You can choose to [overrule this setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script), but it should be done with extreme caution.